# Getting a specific key from Hashmap

Tags: java, android

Am splitting a string with the regular expression `":"`. After splitting the string, and mapping the string using `put()` method from `HashMap()`,when I try to get a specific mapped in key,it returns all mapped in values with ":" from the string.

Here is my code:

```
   public class MyClass {

     private HashMap<String,String> map = null;
     private String newString;


    public MyClass(String newString) {
        this.newString = newString;
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public static MyClass ReadEntityRequest(String string) {
        MyClass Request = new MyClass(string);

        String[] arraystring = Request.string.split("\r\n", 2);
        String[] arraystring1 = arraystring[1].replace("\r\n\r\n", "").split("\r\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < arraystring1.length; i++){
        String[] arraystring2 = arraystring1[i].split(":");
        Request.map.put(arraystring2[0], arraystring[1]);
        }

        return Request;
    }


    public String getHeaderField(String string) {
        String headerField = map.get(string);
        if(headerField != null){
            return headerField;
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

Below is the method calling to get the specific key **"Content-Length"**.

```
MyClass newRequest = MyClass.ReadEntityRequest(newStream);
int contLengthOffset = Integer.parseInt(newRequest.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));
```

My desired result is to get only the key word **"Content-Length"** from the string.
Will be happy to provide more code if necessary. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain, what this line doing `String[] arraystring = Request.string.split("\r\n", 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be putting the same value for all keys in the map:

```
Request.map.put(arraystring2[0], arraystring[1]);
```

Try:

```
Request.map.put(arraystring2[0], arraystring2[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code having some bug. Please see below changes. Now it should work.

```
public static MyClass ReadEntityRequest(String string) {
    MyClass Request = new MyClass(string);

    String[] arraystring = Request.newString.split("\r\n", 2);
    String[] arraystring1 = arraystring[1].replace("\r\n\r\n", "").split("\r\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < arraystring1.length; i++){
    String[] arraystring2 = arraystring1[i].split(":");
    Request.map.put(arraystring2[0], arraystring2[1]);
    }

    return Request;
}
```